# SQL stored procedure inserting duplicate OrderNumber

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, duplicates

I searched the Internet for days, no effort, maybe I cant ask in a right way.

I have a sql table like this:

```
create table Items 
(
    Id int identity(1,1), 
    OrderNumber varchar(7), 
    ItemName varchar(255), 
    Count int
)
```

Then I have a stored procedure inserting items, on demand creating new `OrderNumber`:

```
create procedure spx_insertItems
   @insertNewOrderNr bit,
   @orderNumber varchar(7),
   @itemName varchar(255),
   @count int
as
begin
set nocount on;

  if (@insertNewOrderNr = 1)
   begin
    declare @newNr = (select dbo.fun_getNewOrderNr())
    INSERT INTO Items (OrderNumber, ItemName, Count) values (@newNr, @itemName, @count)
    select @newNr
   end
  else
   begin
    INSERT INTO Items (OrderNumber, ItemName, Count) values (@orderNumber, @itemName, @count)
    select scope_identity()

   end

end
```

Finally there is a user defined function returning new `OrderNumber`:

```
create function dbo.fun_getNewOrderNr
()
return varchar(7)
as
begin

 /* this func works well */

 declare @output varchar(7)
 declare @currentMaxNr varchar(7) 
 set @currentMaxNr = (isnull((select max(OrderNumber) from Items), 'some_default_value_here')
 /* lets assume the @currentMaxNr is '01/2014', here comes logic that increments to @newValue='02/2014' and sets to @output, so: */
 set @output = @newValue

 return @output

end
```

Into Items can be inserted items that do as well that do not belong to any `OrderNumber`.

Whether an Item should become new `OrderNumber`, the procedure is called with `@insertNewOrderNr=1`, returns the new order number, that can be used to insert next items with that `OrderNumber` while `@insertNewOrderNr=0`.

Occasionally there happens that there come simultaneously 2 requests to `@insertNewOrderNr` and THERE IS THE PROBLEM - `Items`, that should correspond with different `OrderNumbers` get the same `OrderNumber`.

I tried to use transaction with no success.

The table structure cant be modified by me.

What would be the right way to ensure, that there won't be used the same `newOrderNumber` when simultaneous requests to the procedure come? 
I am stuck here for a long time till now. Please, help.

Comment: what is return @newValue in your fun_getNewOrderNr

Comment: the @newValue is OrderNumber incremented +1 towards highest existing OrderNumber; the function itself works like a charm, returns values, that are correct (just incremented +1)

Comment: @paulbailey: thanks for reformatting, it is better readable now :)

Comment: Thanks to others for reformatting to..

Comment: Refer this : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9813/how-sql-server-handles-concurrent-requests

Answer (score 0):

You will have that problem as long as you use MAX(OrderNumber).

You might consider using sequences:

**Create sequence**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.OrderNumbers
    AS int
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1 
    NO CACHE;
GO

CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.OrderNumberYear
    AS int
    START WITH 2014 
    INCREMENT BY 1 
    NO CACHE;
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.OrderNumberYear; --Important, run this ONE time after creation, this years value must be returned one initial time to work correctly.
```

**Insert code**

```
DECLARE @orderNumberYear INT = (SELECT CONVERT(INT, current_value) FROM sys.sequences WHERE name = 'OrderNumberYear');

IF(@orderNumberYear < YEAR(GETDATE()))
BEGIN
    SELECT @orderNumberYear = NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.OrderNumberYear;   
    ALTER SEQUENCE dbo.OrderNumbers RESTART WITH 1 ;
END

IF(@orderNumberYear != YEAR(GETDATE()))
    RAISERROR(N'Order year sequence is out of sync.', 16, 1);

DECLARE @newNr VARCHAR(15) = CONCAT(FORMAT(NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.OrderNumbers, '00/', 'en-US'), @orderNumberYear);
INSERT INTO Items (OrderNumber, ItemName, Count) values (@newNr, @itemName, @count)
SELECT @newNr
```

Comment: The format of the OrderNumber has to fit some rules:
- the format is 01/2014, 02/2014..
- the numberst must be a sequence of numbers 01,02.. without break
- every year starts again from 01/[year] so IMHO the sequence is not applicable here because of just one neverending list of numbers

Comment: The MAX function works well athough there is a string value in OrderNumber.

Comment: You still run the risk of getting the same value, I will update the answer with an altered suggestion.

Comment: @Vladimír Hála: I added another sequence for the year. If the year changes the OrderNumbers sequence will be restarted.

Comment: Oops, my mistake, sequences are supported in MS SQLs since version 2012? The server is running 2008r2 version. Sorry for omitting that information!
I found [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askjay/archive/2012/10/08/sequence-objects-in-sql-2012-and-sql-2008.aspx) and try to understand the 2008 part.

Comment: No problem @Vladimír Hála. Yes it was added in MS SQL 2012. Let me know if it works out for you with the mimicked behavior. I can update the answer with a MS SQL 2008 suggestion, if you need it.

Comment: I found that the base problem was tied in running 2 planned queries at the same time so they used the same procedure. After I fixed the start times of the queries, I LUCKILY don't have to try that situation.

Comment: Thanks all for trying to help, it seems no there is no need to enforce the logic since the occasion to have 2 or more concurrent queries towards the logic at the same time is no minimal.

Answer (score 0):

The duplicity still occured, not so often, but did.

The trick I finally used to get around didn't find itself inside SQL. Since the DB is always used by ONLY one web app that is used by several users, this is the solution:

in all (about 5) places in my VB.NET code I surrounded the `myCommand.ExecuteScalar()` with `SyncLock` ([read more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a86s51t(v=vs.140).aspx)) statement that DID the trick :)